# searching related data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

i want to search projects  for specific users using  relations in laravel
but for reason it give me a wrong response all projects of all users . i try many solutions but without solution so any help guys?
this Projet.php:

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->using('App\ProjetUser')->withPivot([
    'user_id',
    'projet_id',
]);
```

this User.php:

```
  public function projets(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Projet')->using('App\ProjetUser');
}
```

and this the function for searching :

```
 if($search = \Request::get('s')){
       $projets=Projet::with('users')->
     where(function($query) use ($search){
          $query->where('name','LIKE',"%$search%")->Orwhere('owner','LIKE',"%$search%")->Orwhere('duration','LIKE',"%$search%")
          ->Orwhere('budget','LIKE',"%$search%");
      })->get();
    }
    return response()->json([
      "projets"=>$projets
  ]);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you or result are getting after running your query?

Comment: it return me all the project.not the project of specific user @livresonltc

Comment: Also the problem with your query is that, you are searching column(name,owner,budget) with one search word. What the query is doing is that it is searching an 's' inside all tree columns and returns all row that contains 's' on your database table. That's why it will not return a specific user.

Comment: @piky, you want result as specify user, then you need to specify the user id. Because its `belongsToMany` relationship

Comment: @STA the auth()->user()->id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if($search = \Request::get('s')){
       $projets=Projet::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->where('users.id', auth()->user()->id);
           })
          ->where(function($query) use ($search){
          $query->where('name','LIKE',"%$search%")->orWhere('owner','LIKE',"%$search%")->orWhere('duration','LIKE',"%$search%")
          ->orWhere('budget','LIKE',"%$search%");
      })->get();
    }
    return response()->json([
      "projets"=>$projets
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous . Not working

Comment: sorry but same problem  Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @piky would you try again `users.id` instead of `id`?

Comment: So it's the accepted answer, but what made it work other than "try this"?

Comment: @dbf, `whereHas()` method, to specific the user get all related specific project

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `orWhere`, not `Orwhere`.

Like this:

```
$projets = Projet::where(function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('owner', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('duration', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('budget', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
})
->with('users')
->get();
```

If you want to search in projects that is related to current logged in user only, you can do it like this:

```
$projets = Projet::where(function($q) use ($search) {
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('owner', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('duration', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('budget', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
})
->whereHas('users', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', auth()->user()->id);
})
->with('users', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', auth()->user()->id);
})
->get();
```

However, it's a bit confusing that way. I would turn it around, and start from the user, and work my way down to project, like this:

```
if (!auth()->check()) {
    die('not logged in?');
}

// Get user obj
$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

// Get search input
$search = \Request::get('s');

// Eloquent find projects
$projets = $user->projets();

// Search has a value
if (is_string($search) && strlen($search) > 0) {

    // Search in users project
    $projets = $projects->where(function($q) use($search) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('owner', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('duration', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('budget', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
    });
}

$projects = $projects->get();

return response()->json([
    "projets" => $projets
]);
```

Comment: What result do you want? And can you provide example of data that is not supposed to be in the returned collection?

Comment: user (id,name)
projet(id,name)
projet_user(id,projet_id,user_id)
user(id:1,name:sam)
projet(id:2,name:logo)
projet(id:4,name:logo)
projet_user(id:1 ,projet_id:2,user_id:1)
 and i want if sam login and search for logo project it return just the project who sam belongsto (id:2) not all project

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($search = \Request::get('s')){
       $projets=Projet::with(['users' => function($query) use ($search){
          $query->where('name','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->orWhere('owner','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->orWhere('duration','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->orWhere('budget','LIKE',"%$search%");
      }])->get();
    }
    return response()->json(["projets"=>$projets]);
  }
```

Comment: not working and show me this error "Call to undefined function App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\where()","